# Appium - How to count elements for static/not scrollable recycleview

Tags: java, android, selenium, android-recyclerview, appium

Hi currently I am trying to implement a test case where I have to get the count of number of elements from a non scrollable reclyeview.

I tried to get the recycleview and add it into a list but it always showing only one item. I am using xpath. But I have the id also.

```
public static final String dashboard_recycleview_xpath = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.ListView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView";

public boolean ticketPurchaseFromDashboardTest() throws InterruptedException, IOException {    
    boolean testPassed = false;
    skipToDashboard();

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(WaitingTime.oneSecond);
    helper.performClick(AndroidIdentifiers.dashboard_buy_a_ticket, true);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(WaitingTime.oneSecond);
    helper.findListViewContent(AndroidIdentifiers.dashboard_recycleview_xpath, false);
    //

    return testPassed;

    //Check if an element of the screen that should appear in the end of the test is there
}

public boolean findListViewContent(String elementId, boolean xPath) {
    //driver.findElements(by.xpath(elementId));
    //driver.findElements(By.xpath(elementId)).
    List weekObjectList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(elementId));
    System.out.println(weekObjectList.size());
    return true;
}
```

I want the correct result. The recycleview holds 3 items initially and after clicking more button it will show 7 items.

Layout:

[image: Layout]

Element Inspection Screen:

[image]

Comment: can u add element inspection screen?

Comment: please open your app through appium desktop inspector and add the screen shot of the your element so that i can help you

Comment: Hello all I updated the post with image links